# Figures on report counter page (without styling)

Tags: floats, report, displaystyle

**Context :**

I am writing a report with article style in latex and I am wondering if it is possible to have :

- on right page : my **usual text**, my full report **without figures** ;
- on counter page (left page) : only the figures that are referenced on their right page, **with no styling**, **only the figure environment** in terms of displays.

Some other requirements would be that the list of figures refers to the page where figures are referenced (on the right page) - and not the counter page. The counter page will not be counted as a page.

---

**My question :**

Is there an automatic way to do so ? I mean, writing my report completely as usual (text and figures in the same file), and then, with a special configuration, figures are automatically displayed on the counter page when compiling (no numbering at all).